# Evaluate Double Integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate the following double integral:

$$\int _0^{2\pi }\int _0^1 \left(x - 2x^2 \sin\left(y\right) \cos\left(x^2+1\right)\right) \text dx\,\text dy$$

Please note that the answer is ${\pi}$

Comment: Do you mean$$\int _0^{2\pi}\int _0^{12} x^2 \sin\left(y\right)\cos\left(x^2+1\right) \;dxdy$$? or does the $x^2$ belong in the upper limit?

Comment: yes, except that it's not 12, the 2 belongs to x^2 , so the limit is from 0 to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int _0^{2\pi}\int _0^1 \left(x - 2x^2 \sin\left(y\right) \cos\left(x^2+1\right)\right)\text dx\,\text dy \\
= \int _0^{2\pi }\left(\int _0^1 x \,\text dx - \int _0^1 2x^2 \sin\left(y\right) \cos\left(x^2+1\right)\,\text dx\right) \text dy \\
= \int _0^{2\pi }\left(\frac 1 2 - \sin\left(y\right) \int _0^1 2x^2  \cos\left(x^2+1\right)\,\text dx\right) \text dy\\
= \int _0^{2\pi }\left(\frac 1 2 - a \sin\left(y\right) \right) \text dy\\
= \left[\frac y 2 + a \cos(y)\right]_0^{2\pi} = \pi$$
Where the fact was used, that integration over a full period of $\sin(y)$ is $0$. Therefore, the value of $\int _0^1 2x^2  \cos\left(x^2+1\right)\,\text dx$ is not really necessary as long as the integral is bounded.